# Printing ith row jth column value in lisp

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, lisp, clisp

I am taking input N as number of rows of a 2D matrix in lisp, where each row can have maximum of 5 elements in it. So i make it like this. Now for eachrow as it can have any number of elements between 0 to 5. So I made a sepearte array to store size of each row of 2D matrix and increment it whenever I push any element in it

```
(setq myMatrix (make-array (list N 5)))

(setq sizeArray (make-list N:initial-element 0))
```

Now when I need add elements to any row I take input while the row has maximum elements or user himself exits to enter any more elements in that row. To add an element to ith row I do something like this :

```
(setf (aref myMatrix i (nth i sizeArray)) "Hi")
// Hi is just for example here
(setf (nth i sizeArray) (+ 1 (nth i sizeArray)))
```

Now I want to print say ith row of this myMatrix Like this :

```
Item 1 : myMatrix[i][0]
Item 2 : myMatrix[i][1]..and so on
```

In direct way, I want jth value of ith row. How we can get this in lisp ?

Comment: First of all, if number of elements in a row can be different for different rows, it's not a matrix. You probably want vector of extensible vectors or lists (5 is not that big number, so you can afford yourself use of lists, in fact it can be even faster than vector-based approach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using an array of lists how about:

```
(defun element-of-matrix (matrix i j)
  (nth j (aref matrix i)))
```

Comment: Got error that 
 AREF: got 1 subscripts, but
  #2A(("A" "B" "C" NIL NIL)
      ("D" "E" NIL NIL NIL))
 has rank 2

Comment: then you are using an array of arrays, not an array of lists:
you just need: 
    (aref matrix i j)
    
    example
    > (setf a (make-array '(2 2)))
    #2A((NIL NIL) (NIL NIL))
    >(setf (aref a 1 1) "hello")
    "hello"
    >(aref a 1 1)
    "hello"

Comment: That is not an array of arrays but a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Indeed Svante, it is a two-dimensional array, my bad.